# Is there a way to use the old smoke simulator in blender 2.82?

Tags: smoke-simulation, versions

In blender 2.82 they introduced Mantaflow simulations and it's been working extremely well for me, however, I can't seem to make multicoloured smoke. Changing the smoke colour in the emitter settings changes the colour for the whole simulation. So I just want to know if it's possible to use the old smoke simulator, as I don't want to load up an old version of blender every time I want to do something like this

Comment: No, Unless you want to develp a new add-on. You might be able to simulate in 2.81 and import to 2.82+